# How do I modify this condition to accept another possibility?

Tags: c

Currently, I have this:

```
printf("%c", board[down][across] == 0 ? 'O' : 'X');
```

Which means -  If the value at this position in the array is 0, display 'O',  otherwise display 'X'

How do I modify this so that:

If the value at this position in the array is 0, display 'O', or if the value is 1 then display 'X' or if the value is 2 display '#'?

I understand I can just use if statements and use the printf line multiple times, but is there a better way of doing so, in one line, like above?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the conditionals to arrive at the value and then print one statement containing that value. Don;t write cryptic code just because it can be written.

Comment: Make a function that takes a value and returns a `char`. Use `if else` or `switch case`. Nice and basic.

Comment: "better" is subjective

Comment: Remember, a lookup table is always preferable over a conditional branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way is to add an extra condition:

```c
grid[down][across] == 0 ? 'O' : grid[down][across] == 1 ? 'X' : '#'
```

This is parsed as

```c
grid[down][across] == 0 ? 'O' : (grid[down][across] == 1 ? 'X' : '#')
```

So you'll get the desired result that 0 → `O`, 1 → `X` and everything else → `#`.

---

Apparently it's going to be a mess if you want some more values (e.g. 3, 4, 5 and so on). If you can make some assumption or guarantee about your values, like it will always be non-negative and bounded, you can use an array to hold your characters:

```c
const char LEGEND[] = {'O', 'X', '#'};
// ...
printf("%c", LEGEND[grid[down][across]]);
```

This has the advantage that you can easily add more values, for example:

```c
const char LEGEND[] = {'O', 'X', '#', '!', '?', '.'};
```

but of course, it's never bad to check if the value is within the desired range before using it as array indices. So your code should be:

```c
int ind = grid[down][across];
// Assume you're using 3 characters
if (ind < 0 || ind >= 3) {
    puts("Oops!");
    exit(1);
}
printf("%c", LEGEND[ind]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a function that takes the grid value and returns the `char`.

Ensure you handle unknown values as you must always `return` something.

```c
char get_char(int const grid_value)
{
  switch (grid_value)
  {
    case 0:
      return 'O';

    case 1:
      return 'X';

    case 2:
      return '#';

    default:
      return '?';
  }
}
```

then just

```c
printf("%c", get_char(board[down][across]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array with possible values:

```
char values[3] = {'O', 'X', '#'};
```

and then simply

```
printf("%c", values[grid[down][across]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest ternary operator.

```
printf("%c", grid[down][across] == 0 ? 'O' : grid[down][across] == 1 ? 'X' : '#');
```

But sure don't use such that code in production!

Comment: @underscore_d Demonstration by counter-example is a powerful tool. This both answers the question posed and suggests moving to a different path. Perfect!